# C fwrite char array

Tags: c, buffer, fwrite, file-writing, file-pointer

This is a function that use a set of predefined code to encode input file (infp) to output file (outfp) (in normal text mode)

```
void encode( char *codes[], FILE *infp, FILE *outfp) {
    while (infp) {
        if (feof(infp)) {
            break;
        }
        char buffer[256];
        sprintf(buffer, "%s", codes[fgetc(infp)]);
        printf("%lu, %s\n", strlen(buffer), buffer); //this works
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), outfp);
    }
};
```

codes is an array of char array with size 256 
for example codes[65] returns the code of ascii char A 
but then the length of code is different for each ascii char, and the max is 256

the printf line works perfectly fine, I got something like for example:

```
6, 100110
5, 00000
4, 0010
3, 110
5, 01011
4, 0001
```

so I expect the output text file will be 100110000000010110010110001 
but I got nothing for the fwrite line, i.e. the output text file is blank, 
not until I put the 3rd argument into 256, i.e.

```
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 256, outfp);
```

but the output sticks with a lot of null and weird characters
[image]

Please help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See definition of feof() [feof() reference][1]
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/feof

> "For example, if a file contains 10 bytes and you read 10 bytes from
> the file, feof will return 0 because, even though the file pointer is
> at the end of the file, you have not attempted to read beyond the end.
> Only after you try to read an 11th byte will feof return a nonzero
> value."

while doesn't stop (it's useless condition, by the way), and feof() doesn't return 1 until it's too late, you get -1 from fgetc(), and use this as index in array, probably get exception, and program crashes before closing output file.

```
if (!infp || !outfp) {
    // Check that files opened successfully
    return;
}

while (true) {
    int index = fgetc(infp);
    if (index < 0) {
        // fgetc() return -1 on end of file
        break;
    }
    char buffer[256];
    sprintf(buffer, "%s", codes[index]);
    printf("%lu, %s\n", strlen(buffer), buffer); //this works
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), outfp);
}
...
// Output file must be closed, otherwise it will be empty
fclose(outfp);
```

Comment: Really thank you for telling me that! But the main problem is the line fwrite doesn't work though >< it just doesn't write properly...

Comment: oh I forgot to change the below one into index... it works perfectly fine!! thank you so much! ToT